# How to create a graph for a table with ratings in Excel

Tags: excel, graph

I have some data which I need to represent in graph in the most suitable way.
[image: On top I have headings as in name of the rating and underneath it I have ratings given by people i.e. between 1 - 6]

Any idea how can I make a suitable graph with this info? Using the normal options in Excel gives a very cluttered look and makes it unreadable.

Comment: Each graph is for a different purpose. Without knowing what you want to achieve, it is impossible to answer your question. It would also be useful to know what you`ve tried so far and how it fails to achieve your desired goal. Finally, this question may be more appropriate to [Superuser](https://superuser.com)

Comment: So basically I tried the graphs available in Excel itself, such as Bar charts and Pie but with that they become too cluttered. What I would ideally like to know is how can I present this data without making multiple graphs.